# Checkout button not working after I upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7. - Am I missing something?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, onepage-checkout, magento-1.6

The store works when I add an item, but when I click to checkout the link re-directs to the home page store. It's the same when I click on Proceed to checkout. Before, I had the cache management disabled and now is enabled. Is this related or what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Did you check the logfiles and error reports?
Maybe yo can find there a hint about your problem.

Comment: Thanks Andre, where could I find this reports?

Comment: @Jacman did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably form key issue. New versions have added this security check.